# Attempt to create a password prompt and checker to allow exiting the program

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I appreciate your kind attention!
Here's my problem: I have a menubar that has an exit option. When it is click on, a window will popup prompting the user to enter Admin Access Password before allowing them to exit the main application
I have changed my code over and over yet I still get the same problem
This is my code right now

```
def exitmenu():

def exitmenucheck():
    if passwordentry.get() == actualpassword:
        quit
    else:
        popupmsg("error")

exitmenu= tk.Tk()
exitmenu.wm_title("Administrator Access")

label = ttk.Label(exitmenu, text="Enter Password.", font=NORM_FONT)
label.grid(row=0,column=0)

password = tk.StringVar()
passwordentry = tk.Entry(exitmenu, textvariable=password, show='*')
passwordentry.grid(row=0,column=1)

button = ttk.Button(exitmenu, text="Exit", command=exitmenucheck, width=8)
button.bind('<Enter>',exitmenucheck)
button.grid(row=2,column=1,sticky="s")
```

And here is the error that I get whenever I key in the correct or the wrong password

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1562, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: exitmenucheck() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1562, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: exitmenucheck() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

Sorry I have only started python programming 2 days ago so this may seem like a very simple task that is impossible to mess up.
Thank you for your patience and guidance in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should`actualpassword` be string `'actualpassword'` so change the part by adding `parenthesis` to it.

```
def exitmenucheck():
    if passwordentry.get() == 'actualpassword':
        quit
    else:
        popupmsg("error")
```

See this example from your code

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox   


def exitmenu():
    pass

def exitmenucheck(event=None):
    if passwordentry.get() == "actualpassword":
        exitmenu.destroy()
    else:
        messagebox.showwarning("error", "password incorrect")
       # popupmsg("error")
        print("error")


exitmenu= tk.Tk()
exitmenu.wm_title("Administrator Access")

label = ttk.Label(exitmenu, text="Enter Password.")
label.grid(row=0,column=0)

password = tk.StringVar()
passwordentry = tk.Entry(exitmenu, textvariable=password, show='*')
passwordentry.bind("<Return>", exitmenucheck)
passwordentry.grid(row=0,column=1)

button = ttk.Button(exitmenu, text="Exit", command=exitmenucheck, width=8)
# button.bind('<Enter>',exitmenucheck)
button.grid(row=2,column=1,sticky="s")

exitmenu.mainloop()
```

You should `bind` your to `entry` widget rather than `button` widget and you should bind `keyboard enter key` rather which is `Return`

Comment: Thank you for your help! However, I have added the parenthesis and I still get the same error

Comment: I would have used:-

enteredpassword = passwordentry.get() followed by:- 
if enteredpassword == 'actualpassword':
.......

Comment: Now im getting a new error :
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1562, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: exitmenucheck() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

Comment: Yes, it is working now! Thank you so much for your help!